# This Python fibonacci number function produces 0.0 for any input. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, division, fibonacci

This function is supposed to produce the corresponding fibonnacci number given the step in the fibonacci sequence, but it just produces 0 with any input. Before, every number in the code below had no ".0" after it, and the function produced the numbers it was supposed to, but when I divided the results, they always produced "1.0". Here is the code:

```
def f(number):
    return (1.0//math.sqrt(5.0))*((((1.0+math.sqrt(5.0))//2.0)**number)-(((1.0-math.sqrt(5.0))/2.0)**number))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *when I divided results from different inputs by each other, they always produced 1.0

Comment: You explicitly do `1.0 // math.sqrt(5.0)`. What did you expect out it? Hint, hint...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you've jammed the whole thing on one line? It's very hard to read this way.

Comment: `//` is integer division; `1.0//math.sqrt(5.0)` is 0.0.

Comment: In the interactive shell, type `1.0//2.0` and `1.0/2.0` and compare...

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly requesting floored division with `//`, so `1.0//math.sqrt(5.0)` is 0. Use regular division:

```
1.0/math.sqrt(5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace all your `//` with `/`

Like:

```
def f(number):
    return (1.0/math.sqrt(5.0))*((((1.0+math.sqrt(5.0))/2.0)**number)-(((1.0-math.sqrt(5.0))/2.0)**number))
```

Keep in mind that `//` is integer division.